# creating createM3FromEclipseProject in Rascal creates no data

Tags: rascal

I'm new to Rascal and have a very very basic question.

I'm using in a little test project the follwing command :

```
createM3FromEclipseProject(|project://example-project|);
```

and uses the code to extract data from a project

It only gives my {}... I assume that means that my M3 model is empty.
What am I doing wrong? It has to be something really basic..

Greets
Doerak

Comment: nice name for a Rascal user :-)

Comment: It's a good question that more people have run into lately. So if you have found a solution, please mention this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the recipe in http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Recipes/Recipes.html#/Recipes/Metrics/MeasuringJava/MeasuringJava.html ?

If no: then please do because that example code is tested.

If yes, then it means there is no data in your project. This can be caused by:

- there really is no code in your project. This can be remedied :-)
- or the source path of the example project (with the Java code) is not configured to point to the place where you have your Java code. This can be fixed in the properties pane (right-click on the project and its the bottom option). From there on, find help on managing Eclipse projects on stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Thanks for responding, Yes, I followed the recipe;

Comment: Thanks for responding, Yes, I followed the recipe; importing M3 core/jdt and then trying to access the model by means of an example project, interesting is that the call  set[loc] bestanden = javaBestanden(|project://jabber|); works fine! I get a nice list of all java files. This indicates that my jabber example project is in the right place... why is my M3 empty? As soon as I want to read my classes and/or methods it goes blank..

Comment: rascal>opgave7();
(7a)
15
(7b)
XMLAccessor.java: 112 regels
MenuController.java: 109 regels
TextItem.java: 108 regels
Presentation.java: 107 regels
Slide.java: 85 regels
BitmapItem.java: 67 regels
SlideViewerComponent.java: 62 regels
Style.java: 57 regels
DemoPresentation.java: 50 regels
KeyController.java: 44 regels
SlideItem.java: 38 regels
JabberPoint.java: 37 regels
SlideViewerFrame.java: 36 regels
Accessor.java: 30 regels
AboutBox.java: 28 regels
(7c)
(7d)
ok

Comment: Sorry for the lay-out.. just wanted to show opgave7 :-)

Comment: hi @dod101 it's not about just the files but also about the project meta data. The Java compiler must be able to see the source files. So how is your project's source folder configured?

Comment: rascal>javaBestanden(|project://jabber/|);
set[loc]: {
  |project://jabber/JabberPoint/src/KeyController.java|,
  |project://jabber/JabberPoint/src/BitmapItem.java|,
  |project://jabber/JabberPoint/src/JabberPoint.java|,......}

Comment: The javaBestanden method -for testing- is very simple and sees the actual .java files in the directory, as you can see the eclipse project jabber (java-project) has a dir:JabberPoint/src, which contains all .java files. It should recognize this... imho..

Comment: <m3(|project://jabber|)[@implements={},@types={},@typeDependency={},@methodInvocation={},@documentation={},@fieldAccess={},@methodOverrides={},@annotations={},@modifiers={},@declarations={},@containment={},@names={},@extends={},@messages=[],@uses={}]>

Comment: the above comment shows what I get from M3 model when just dumping it to the console..

Comment: I'll keep testing this.. if I find anything I'll post it, let me know when you get tired of me :-)

Comment: You are missing an important point in my feedback. Did you check the source path setting of your Eclipse project? the `javaBestanden` thing is not telling you anything about that point, just that the files are there, but not if they are being looked at.

Comment: I checked the sourcepath on the rascal project and added the example project to project tab, this gave me an stack overflow error in eclipse and had to delete this setting. The source tab only holds the rascalproject/src folder. Or is there any other source folder I should take a look at?

Comment: rascal project: java buildpath in the properties settings; source tab holds the rascalproject/src

Comment: OK, I have something going! It's a work around or may be it is suppose to work like that.. at least I have my M3 model loaded and its possible to count classes and methods.

Comment: What did i do? I took the eclipse project (which is subject to extraction by Rascal project) and COPIED the applicable java sources into the /src directory of the Rascal project. Now I don't have to worry about path settings, andsoforth...

Comment: I'm going to take this (work around) approach in order to work on my model, it seems to do the trick. Thanks for your help jurgenv! Greetz Doerak

Comment: the problem was in the source path of the example project :)